# Return values in switch statements

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, return

**Background**: I'm creating a program for a school assignment that simulates a shopping cart. I've added a switch statement to display data and calculate item sub-total. This so far is working, I can calculate the sub total and when selecting two of the same item for purchase the subtotal reflects the total of the bulk items. My issue lies in adding the subtotals together for a final total.

Should I just separate everything into if statements or can I return a full total at the end of my switch statement?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<!Doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>""</title>
    <script>
        function CheckOut() {

            // variable declaration 

            let product = ["Winter Hat", "Warm Coat", "Gloves"];
            let prices = [27.50, 160.23, 23.99];

            let product_code = parseInt(document.forms.myform.product.value);
            let product_quanity = parseInt(document.forms.myform.quanity.value);

            let total = 0;

            /* generates a list of shopping items. Users will enter a product code (1-3) and the quanity of the product they wish to buy. 
             The sub total for these products are then added together to output an final total. */

            switch (product_code) {
                case 1:
                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("Winter Hat" + "[" + product_quanity + "]");
                    total += product_quanity * prices[0];
                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "$" + total.toFixed(2) + "<br>";
                    break;

                case 2:

                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("Warm Coat" + "[" + product_quanity + "]");
                    total += product_quanity * prices[1];
                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "$" + total.toFixed(2) + "<br>";
                    break;

                case 3:
                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("Gloves" + " [" + product_quanity + "]");
                    total += product_quanity * prices[2];
                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "$" + total.toFixed(2) + "<br>";

                    break;

                default:
                    alert("Please input a number between 1 - 3.");

            }

         
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    This is the point of sale program for a store selling winter cloths.
    <ul> 
        <li>Product Code 1 : A Winter Hat costs $27.50</li>
        <li>Product Code 2 : A Warm Coat costs $160.23</li>
        <li>Product Code 3 : A pair of gloves costs $32.99</li> 
    </ul>

    <form name=myform action="javascript:CheckOut()">

        Product Code: <input type="text" name="product" id="product"><br>
        Quanity: <input type="text" name="quanity" id="quanity"><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <div id="results"></div>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: *can I return a full total at the end of my switch statement?* <-- Have you tried that?

Comment: It looks like your checkout function just gives the subtotal for each item. If you want it to calculate the grand total, you need to keep track of the product code and quantity for each item they "add" to the cart. I say "add" because right now you're not storing that info anywhere, so currently your system does not effectively "add to cart".